# Adding std::tuple to std::map compiles and works on Macos, not on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, macos, stl

Here is the following code (assuming *id* and *speed* are already initialised, and includes are correct):

`std::map<int, std::tuple<double, double>> mymap;`

`mymap.insert(std::pair<int, std::tuple<double, double>>(id, speed));`

This code compiles and works under Macos (Xcode using clang-800.0.42.1) **and** Linux (Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0).

`mymap.insert(std::tie(id, speed));`

This code compiles and works under Macos (Xcode using clang-800.0.42.1), but **not** under Linux (Ubuntu 16.04, gcc 5.4.0). For the latter, the error raised is:

`error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<int, std::tuple<double, double> >::insert(std::tuple<int&, std::tuple<double, double>&>)`

Note that the problem is similar when trying to insert an std::tuple to an std::map (bypassed by using std::pair instead of std::tuple).

Can anyone explain? Thanks!

Comment: Note that compiling under Linux with clang works. Still the question remains: why does it works with clang and not gcc?

Comment: Note also: I compile with: g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++11 (comment added after Lilit Zakaryan answer -- I should have specified this first hand, thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Tuples are added to C++ form C++11.

[std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)

For use of C++11 features you need to add -std=c++11 flag to your
gcc compiler by default it is not activated yet.

I think mac compiles because you are using Xcode and maybe the -std=c++11 flag is already set from IDA.

Comment: Actually I do compile using the following (and still get the error): g++ -Wall -O3 -std=c++11